# ElasticSearch Upsert or Index what is correct my case?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have two different Spark jobs that feeds the same index on ElasticSearch one fill a certain set of fields and the other auguments the index with the rest of the data.

My question is, should I use index (I think the answer is no, I would loose data from the first job AFAIK) or upsert?

In case it's upsert (which is the one I am playing with right now), it allows FORCE/INTERNAL versioning types, FORCE in theory shouldn't be used, even though it's the one that fits to my needs from a simple testing perspective.

When I try internal I have a version conflict that says that current version is -1 and I am trying to set it to 1. Is it safe to set the version to -1 simply to use INTERNAL instead of FORCE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use upsert for your use case [read more](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts)

For the first case, it will insert the index if it's not their second if the document is there it will just append the values to your document.

Comment: The problem that I have is that whenever using upsert, data being updated is always throwing version conflict error that I've mentioned ("version conflict, current version [-1] is different than the one provided [1]") except if I set versioning type to FORCE, which according to the doc should be avoided.

Comment: This happens only when you do a parallel update on one document. You shouldn't be using FORCE as that might mess up your data. I the document is being got updated and the same document is opened by some other process parallelly then only you will get version error.

Comment: From my tests, update is not running in parallel, that's for sure. The second operation in general is running some seconds after. If that was the case, a retrial would be enough, wouldn't it?

Comment: You were actually right, initially I missed the fact that this could be happening (synchronization issue), I was able to make it working by setting: es.update.retry.on.conflict to "2" and now the errors went away.

Comment: But this will increase your total process time and if you are using script it might be increased drastically

Comment: What's the solution then? I have 2 jobs writing simultaneously, I don't see any other option, specially considering I cannot set a version since I don't have control over which job will execute first.

Comment: Can't you make them sync or sequential? In which language are you writing in? Like if you want you can use ping pong parallelism technic to have control over them.

Comment: Basically I am receiving events from remote systems through Kafka, so no guarantee on which event will go first. I am writing in Java.